# Install Aptana 2 on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to install Aptana 2 in Ubuntu 13.04. For this I am using this instructions http://gansik.ru/ubuntu/ustanovka-aptana-studio-3/  it is in russian but I suppose the main idea what Ive been trying you can see.

I read that I need to install Java first. So when I make this command sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer it return me Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)  what is wrong? Suggestions?

Comment: Are you installing jdk or sdk ?

Comment: @GeorgeAstonishing I am not sure. I do step by step like in link I mention in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

And finally verify installation by typing:

```
java -version
```

Comment: thats what I am trying. After sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer it return a mistake in terminal like i mentioned in my question

Comment: Can you try apt-get -f install to force an install of the files that didn't get loaded due to the error? ... Try that right after you get the error. If that doesn't work can you post a full trace of what you get in the console before you get the error ? Cheers

Comment: There is a directly the same problem. But I cant to solve this issue http://askubuntu.com/questions/414885/oracle-jdk-7-is-not-installed-error

Comment: Would it be sufficient to install open JDK for running Aptana Studio ? sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk icedtea-7-plugin

Comment: Thanks for your help. I solved problem. Download earliest version of the file that pushed an error and replaced it. Now it installed